# SQLAlchemy: How to update using origin value directly

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In `SQL`, we can write

```
UPDATE Orders SET Stock = Stock - 1 Where id = 1;
```

to update orders **using origin stock's value**.

What about in `SQLAlchemy` ?

```
s = orders.update().where(order.c.id == 1).values(Stock=newStock)
conn.execute(s)
```

here we cannot write `newStock` as `Stock - 1`.

How to update it using origin value directly?

Comment: Is there any reason not to just build the exact query string you defined and issue it with `conn.execute(query_string)`?.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = orders.update().where(order.c.id == 1).values(stock=order.c.stock-1)
conn.execute(s)
```

Comment: [Code-only answers are discouraged.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272)